# Using the same service block for different tasks in anylogic

Tags: anylogic, event-simulation

I am currently busy with a project at a hospital. I need to create a simulation model replicating the processes at the hospital. I have a problem with regards to one counter or service desk at the hospital. The staff member at the service desk needs to perform two different tasks, depending on the type of patient. How do I programme the service block to perform two different tasks?. For now,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FnMo.jpg) I have split the block into two different blocks using the same staff member. Is there another way that I can go about this?

Answer (score 1):

> The staff member at the service desk needs to perform two different tasks, depending on the type of patient.

If the task only differs in duration, you can easily adjust the task duration by patient type in the `Service` delay property (assuming your patients are agents of types `PatientType1` and `PatientType2`):
[image]

For more complex tasks, you can create a function that returns the duration and takes your requesting patient as an input argument, for example `f_getDelayByPatient(MyPatientType patient)`
Then, the service block can use that function in the "Delay time" code section to compute it for each arriving patient using `f_getDelayByPatient(agent)`